# Dagger 2 Injecting parameters in generic class

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have provided a dependency **FirebaseFirestore** in a module and now I am trying to write a generic class and I need to inject **FirebaseFirestore** dependency here but not sure how to do it. here it is what I am doing right now:

```
class PersistenceStore<T> : IPersistenceStore<T> {


@Inject
lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore

   override fun addRow(item: T): T {

   }
}
```

Guide me to the right path please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you know how to inject normally.

**First solution.** Not so generic. Defeats the purpose of generic.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [FireBaseFirestoneModule::class])
interface FireBaseComponent {
    fun inject(PersistenceStore<ActualItemClass> obj) // just put the actual item type in here.
}
```

**Second solution.** Wrapper. Inject the wrapper instead.

```
class PersistenceStore<T> : IPersistenceStore<T> {

   private val injectWrapper = InjectWrapper()

   constructor() {
       DaggerFireBaseComponent().builder().build()
           .inject(injectWrapper) // inject the wrapper
   }

   override fun addRow(item: T): T {

   }
}

class InjectWrapper { // put all injectable variables here
    @Inject
    lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks I also injected the constructor on root level. Now im stuck here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56940711/getting-null-instance-from-dagger-2