# Getting null instance from dagger 2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am developing an app in which I have defined multiple layers and using dagger2 for instance management etc. I have managers, services and views.

I am trying to set manager in a @Module like:

```
@Module
class ManagerModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideDatabaseContext(userManager: UserManager) : DatabaseContext {
    var databaseContext : DatabaseContext = DatabaseContext();
    databaseContext.setUserManager(userManager)
    return databaseContext
}


@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideUserManager(store : PersistenceStore<DAOUser>) : UserManager = UserManager(store)
}
```

where DatabaseContext is like this:

```
class DatabaseContext : IDatabaseContext {


private lateinit var userManager: IUserManager


override fun getUserManager(): IUserManager {
    return userManager;
}

fun setUserManager(userManager: IUserManager){
    this.userManager = userManager;
}

}
```

and when I have injected DatabaseContext in my service like this:

```
class UserService @Inject constructor(var databaseContext: IDatabaseContext) : IUserService {





override fun addUser(dtoUser: DTOUser, callback: ResponseCallback<Response<Void>>) {


    var daoUser : DAOUser = DAOUser(dtoUser.name, dtoUser.email, dtoUser.password)


    databaseContext.getUserManager().add(daoUser);
    callback.onCompletion(Response<Void>())
}
}
```

Everything is working fine except getUserManager() which is coming null all the time even though I have setUserManager method and I am setting in ManagerModule as you can see above. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Here is ServicesModule

```
@Module
class ServicesModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideUserService() : UserService = UserService(DatabaseContext())

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideAuthenticationService() : AuthenticationService = AuthenticationService(FirebaseAuth.getInstance())
}
```

Comment: Is it a typo in your example code that you're providing the `DatabaseContext` as the `DatabaseContext` type, instead of providing it as an `IDatabaseContext`? As it is right now, that `@Provide` function couldn't be the one that's used to inject an `IDatabaseContext`. If your code compiles and runs like this, whatever `IDatabaseContext` you get in `UserService` must be provided from somewhere else.

Comment: Currently it is DatabaseContext. As IDatabaseContext is just an interface with getDatabaseContext method definition inherited by DatabaseContext

Comment: Yup, I get that part. But if your method is returning a `DatabaseContext` type, I believe you shouldn't be able to inject it somewhere as an `IDatabaseContext`. Are you sure you don't have another method that provides the concrete `IDatabaseContext` type somewhere?

Comment: Yes I have provided the concrete DatabaseContext in just manager module. Just in ServicesModule I have used DatabaseContext in constructor. I have added ServicesModule in my question

Comment: I think in ServicesModule I have to do it like this 

@ Provides
@ Singleton
fun provideUserService(databaseContext : DatabaseContext()) : UserService = UserService(databaseContext )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was passing it wrong in the method of ServicesModule. So I had to pass it in the method like this and it worked:

```
 @Provides 
 @Singleton 
 fun provideUserService(databaseContext : DatabaseContext()) : UserService = UserService(databaseContext )
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the null one is actually `databaseContext` instead of `getUserManager()`. Because I'm not sure how you instantiate `UserService`.

Constructor injection requires the class being injected to, to be instantiated in a component that provides the argument type. In your case, since you don't have it, then your `UserService` is actually not getting injected.

Also, `DatabaseContext` provider needs to be in one of the modules where `userService()` is at for `UserService` constructor injection to work, which you have already.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ManagerModule::class]) // ManagerModule has DatabaseContext provider
class MyComponent {
    fun userService(): UserService // this is how you get the instance of userService that is constructor injected. 
}
```

Since the name of your class has Service in it. I assume you want a single instance of it. You can annotate it with `@Singleton` so every `userService()` call returns the same object, otherwise it creates a new object.

```
@Singleton
class UserService @Inject constructor(var databaseContext: IDatabaseContext) : IUserService
```

Comment: IYour syntax seems like dagger 1 but in my case I am using dagger 2. or is it gonna be the same in dagger 2?

Comment: Which one is dagger1 syntax?

Comment: the one you suggested !! I am not sure

Comment: I just fixed your constructor injection problem. I mean, there is another way to fix it but the constructor injection would have to be removed. So yeah, this is the only way to do constructor injection even in dagger2.

Comment: Oh yes man I get it. You are right I injected this like above and changed a little in fun provideUserService() : UserService = UserService(DatabaseContext()) and it worked. have a look at my answer above. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Yeah, your answer should work. But it doesn't need the `@Inject` in the constructor now since you're doing a normal injection now.

Comment: Okay I get it.You mean I have provided the dependency in module and constructor injection doesn't require anymore?

Comment: Yeah, constructor injection is not needed anymore because you explicitly use `UserService(databaseContext)`